# Distribution of ratio of uniform and exponential random variables

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution, ratio

This is a homework question, I feel like I'm doing it right, but I can't seem to get the answer to match up.  I have a uniform RV from 2 to 4, and an exponential with mean 4, so $X \sim \text{UNI}(2,4)$, $Y \sim \text{EXP}(4)$.

I'm looking for the density of $U=\dfrac{Y}{X}$.  So $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}$, $f(y)=\dfrac{e^{-y/4}}{4}$, and $f(x,y)=\dfrac{e^{-y/4}}{8}$.

Now if I substitute $Y=Ux$, and multiply in a Jacobian ($\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}u}ux=x$, this might be a mistake, I'm not completely clear on this), I can get $f(x,u)=\dfrac{xe^{-xu/4}}{8}$.  The marginal density $f(u)$ is found then by integrating out the $x$, which I can do by turning that joint density into a gamma function, where I need to get a $\dfrac{16}{u^2}$ on the bottom, so I end up with $\dfrac{2}{u^2}$ outside of the gamma integral, and after the gamma integrates to 1, f(u)=$\dfrac{2}{u^2}$.  Anyone see a mistake here?

Comment: Well, your method of proceeding is poor, though, regrettably, it is often taught as a recipe that can be followed without thinking too much about what's going on, and so I will not attempt to read through your work to see if there is a mistake. But the _final answer_ should be testable. Since $Y \in (0,\infty)$, $Y/X$ takes on values in $(0,\infty)$ also. Is $2u^{-2}, u > 0$ a valid pdf?

Comment: Thanks.  I'm kind of swimming in new material, and it's easy to overlook the obvious, like does it integrate to 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is clearly wrong since the density does not integrate to $1$ across the positive reals, as Dilip Sarwate.

The way I would approach this would be to take your $f(x,y)=\dfrac{e^{-y/4}}{8}$ and look at 
$$\Pr\left(\frac{Y}{X} \le u\right)=\int_{x=2}^{4} \int_{y=0}^{ux}  \dfrac{e^{-y/4}}{8} dy\, dy= \int_{x=2}^{4}\left(\frac12- \dfrac{e^{-ux/4}}{2}\right) dx $$  $$=1-\frac{2}{u}\left({e}^{-\frac{u}{2}}-{e}^{-{u}}\right),$$ which has the correct limits as $u \to 0$ and $u \to \infty$, and then take the derivative for the density.

Comment: Your method is how I would have done it. I'm led to believe that the assumptions to use the Jacobian method aren't satisfied, and my guess is that $U$ is not one-to-one with respect to $X$ or $Y$. Am I correct?

Comment: @Clarinetist: I try not to use Jacobians or even their 1-dimensional equivalent, since I often find CDFs much easier to work with. $U$ is monotonic with respect to $X$ and with respect to $Y$

Answer (score 1):

You have assumed that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables and so I
suppose that the actual problem you are solving is stating this somewhere,
or it is taken from a section titled Independent Random Variables in some book.

For a (continuous) random variable $Y$ with density $f_Y(y)$, the density of
$Z = aY$ is $$f_Z(z) = \frac{1}{|a|}f_Y\left(\frac za\right).$$
Thus, for $x > 0$, *given* that $X = x$, the *conditional* density of $U =\frac YX = \frac Yx$ is
$$f_{U\mid X}(u \mid X=x) = xf_Y(xu) = \frac{x e^{-xu/4}}{4}.$$
Now  find the *unconditional* density of $U$ using
$$f_U(u) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{U\mid X}(u \mid X=x)f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx
= \int_2^4 \frac{x e^{-xu/4}}{4}\times\frac 12 \,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: This integral gives the same result as the derivative of my expression, as it should.

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the confirmation. I wrote a different answer from yours (which I did upvote) to point out to the OP the implicit assumption of independence and also to give the OP a different approach to the problem.  I am very much of the same view that you expressed in your comment to Clarinetist: that it is easier to work with the CDF instead of Jacobians.